# PhoneGap 3.1.0 difference over 2.9.0?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build, cordova-3

I am using the following to get app's root folder with PhoneGap on iOS. Building with Phonegap Build. It works fine on phonegap 2.9.0, but fails on 3.1.0. Can someone point out what changed, and what may be wrong with the code? Thank you.

```
function findLocalPath()
{
    window.requestFileSystem(  
        LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 
        0,  
        function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem)
        {  
            fileSystem.root.getFile(
                "dummy.html", 
                {create: true, exclusive: false},  
                function gotFileEntry(fileEntry)
                { 
                    var sPath = fileEntry.fullPath.replace("dummy.html","");  
                    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();  
                    fileEntry.remove();

                    alert(sPath);
                },
            fail);
        },  
    fail);
 }
```

In config.xml, I have replaced

```
<plugin name="File" value="CDVFile" />
<plugin name="FileTransfer" value="CDVFileTransfer" />
```

with the following, as docs state.

```
<feature name="File">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFile" />
</feature>
<feature name="FileTransfer">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFileTransfer" />
</feature>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In phonegap 3.x you have to add the plugins using the command line, not changing the config.xml

to add file and file-transfer use this:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file

cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file-transfer
```

It will change the config.xml and add other required files.

For phonegap build you have to add them locally and then build it online with this commands:

```
phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file.git
phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file-transfer.git
phonegap remote build ios
```

Comment: Since I am building app with PhoneGap Build, not locally - how to accomplish this?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't realize you were using phonegap build. Try the edited answer.